# Liferay: How have chat-portlet disabled it's borders?

Tags: chat, border, liferay, portlet

Chat portlet is displayed as a long bar at the bottom of the screen. I want to write a similiar portlet.

I can draw my bar anyway on the screen with CSS styles and also I have learned how to make static portlet visible always for all users with portal-ext.propeties.

But along with my bar, Liferay draws standard portlet frame with a title and controls on it. I found that it is named "topper" in HTML code.

So how to disable topper and border for one specific portlet in the way chat-portlet did it? I failed to figure this out from chat-portlet sources.

I found two options which can be relevant to this

```
<use-default-template>false</use-default-template>
<system>true</system>
```

but they weren't work.

First one causes ClassNotFoundException and second one causes portlet content not reaching page source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was to use

```
<use-default-template>false</use-default-template>
```

correctly. It does not work if placed in incorrect order.